# String or binary data would be truncated, but everything is varchar(max)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query to pivot some tabular data into a JSON-esque string array using a query similar to this:

```
SELECT cr.TableId AS Id,
       cast(quotename(
                       stuff(
                            (SELECT cast(',' AS VARCHAR(max)) + quotename(cast(li.ImageUrl AS VARCHAR(max)), '"')
                             FROM   [DSP].[CreativeLibraryImage] cli WITH (nolock)
                                    INNER JOIN [DSP].[LibraryImage] li WITH (nolock)
                                      ON li.LibraryImageId = cli.[CreativeLibraryImageId]
                             WHERE  cli.TableId = cr.TableId
                             FOR xml path('')
                             ), 1, 1, ''
                             ) --stuff
                      ) --quotename
                      AS VARCHAR(max)
            ) --cast
            AS ImagePaths
FROM   MyTable cr WITH (nolock);
```

I am getting the "String or binary data would be truncated" error halfway through my query, but I think I'm casting all the varchar data to `varchar(max)` data, so I shouldn't have any string length issues.  Clearly there's problem shoehorning this tabular data into a wide column, but I can't see where it could be truncating.

Can someone advise me on what conditions could cause this so that I can compensate accordingly?

Comment: `quotename` accepts parameters of type SYSNAME, which is NVARCHAR(128).

Comment: wow, how lame. Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest taking a peek at this before continuing to use NOLOCK on every single query. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: So it works now with `REPLACE(li.ImageUrl,'"','""')` instead of `QUOTENAME`?

Comment: well, I did a concatenation.  I was looking for encapsulating the data in array brackets and quotation marks (basically a JSON string array, I haven't gotten around to escaping quote chars yet) but it works, and I never would have imagined that `quotename` was so limited in capability.

Comment: Have you head about [`FOR JSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server) in SQL Server 2016+?

Comment: Yeah, but we're not on 2016 (yet)... more's the pity.  This would have been even easier with STRING_AGG in 2017+...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from [BOL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) for `quotename`:

> 'character_string' Is a string of Unicode character data.
>   character_string is sysname and is limited to 128 characters. Inputs
>   greater than 128 characters return NULL.